# Generating a list of double/decimales in Scala

Tags: list, scala

I can generate a list of random values using the following code

```
val foo = Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextInt(100))
```

but how can I have a list of value between 0 and 1 instead?

I tried

```
Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextInt(100)/100)
```

but it produces a list of Int

```
Seq[Int] = List(0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as either the divisor or the dividend is a `Double`, you have [numeric widening implicit conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) which will automatically convert the other argument also to a double. Otherwise, the division is considered as integer division.

```
scala> val foo = Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000)/1000.toDouble)
foo: Seq[Double] = List(0.44, 0.836, 0.426)
```

That said, you should use `nextDouble` if you want this behavior - it generates a random double between `0` and `1`

```
scala> val foo = Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextDouble)
foo: Seq[Double] = List(0.9016195186022057, 0.32388738824301755, 0.09844453536156428)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use like this:

```
Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextFloat)
```

or if you want Double

```
Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextDouble)
```

Here a nice [tip](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch02s08.html) for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Seq.fill(3)(scala.util.Random.nextDouble)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note `math.random` delivers a `Double` between `0` and `1`, hence

```
Seq.fill(3)(math.random)
```

And also

```
Seq.tabulate(3)(_ => math.random)
```